# Phone shows foreign phone numbers as domestic

Tags: calls

I have a Samsung S9+. Sometimes, my phone does show foreign numbers as being calls from abroad (i.e. there's a plus-sign with the country code before the phone number). However, it has happened multiple times that a phone number seems domestic, but is actually international (and, if I call back, I reach somebody entirely different than the one I just talked to).

It seems like the phone has a hard time distinguishing between foreign and some domestic phone numbers.  Sometimes it's kinda obvious (e.g. the phone number has the wrong number of digits). However, other times, there's no way for me to tell that the phone call is actually an international one.

A lot of these international calls are spam calls. Is there a way to work around this issue so that I can always tell if a phone number is a domestic or foreign? I mean, there are certain countries from where there's no reason for anybody there to call me.

Comment: You should complain to your Carrier and they should fix it. This spam calling is a part of illegal calling which I think involves VOIP. In India, we are told by SMS to report to certain numbers, such instances.

Comment: I dug out an old SMS - *While receiving an international call, if an Indian number or no number is displayed on your phone, please inform on the DoT toll free number 1800110420/1963*